# Stop echoing ^C to terminal

Tags: bash

How do I tell my bash to not echo ^C back to terminal?

If I just hit Ctrl+C in bash session, nothing is printed in my terminal window. But if I terminate some program with Ctrl+C, sometimes ^C is echoed and printed in my terminal. Is there any way to tell my bash I do not want echoing back ^C at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I believe it's actually echoing "caret"-C, not the `CTRL-C` character.  Other than that, this is actually a function of the `tty` driver, not the shell; the driver actually intercepts the `CTRL-C` character, generates a `SIGINT` to the process, and echos the characters.  If there is a way to do it on your system (this will be heavily OS dependent) it would be documented in the *stty(1)* man page or the *tty(4)* driver page.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the output with stty works as I wanted it to on OS X, I have still something missing on Linux.

Comment: Well, I said it was heavily system dependent.  At least now you're looking in the right place.

Answer (score 18):

Under Linux:

stty -ctlecho

(props to Charlie for the hint - I just went and looked it up)

Comment: or -echoctl because who wants just *one* flag.

Comment: Well, on my linux box (Ubuntu 8.10) it just changes the output from "^C" to some other character(s), apparently dependent on terminal encoding. On OS X box, manpage says it will echo the CTRL-something "as themself" and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could trap sigint... Put a function into your .bashrc or .profile. Here's my trap on sigint:

```
Trap2 () ( Tred "%6s–<Interrupt>–\n" ''; return 202 ); trap Trap2 SIGINT
```

Where Tred is a function which prints red text. If you want nothing displayed, use this:

```
Trap2 () ( return ); trap Trap2 SIGINT
```

Cheers!

-- ***Aesthir***