# How do I prevent ^C from showing when displayed when pressing CTRL+C

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I am trying to prevent `^C` from showing when a user presses `CTRL+C` while my script is running.

#### Why do I want to prevent that?

Because things like this will happen and it does not look nice:

```
$ python3 myscript.py
^CYour pressed CTRL+C
```

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418073/stop-echoing-c-to-terminal), but it does not work in Python

Comment: instead of stopping that symbol from displaying, perhaps display your message in a new line instead?

Comment: Which terminal are you using?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Kitty terminal, but the terminal emulator does not actually matter.

Comment: It's a feature of the terminal, not of Python. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333766/remove-c-when-ctrlc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop echoing ^C to terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418073/stop-echoing-c-to-terminal)

Comment: I've proposed a simple solution here <https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954578/3057377>

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy method!

```
# Returning the cursor to home and dont create a new line
print("\r", end="")

# Now we are able to print on the line where ^C would be displayed
print("Your pressed CTRL+C")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Because things like this will happen...

Just my two cents: the fact that `^C` displays in the terminal is a *good thing*. It's confirmation that `SIGINT` was sent to the process, as expected. Don't try to remove it; instead, as others have suggested, start a new line if you really want to. Or just exit without printing anything additional at all, like lots of other command line applications.